# How to access current dashboard tab in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

In the Umbraco, if I have a custom Dashboard content tab pointing to an ascx control, how do I determine in the code which tab is accessing the control?
I would like to re-use the same control for different tabs with slight differences.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get TabPage on which a user control data type resides](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539071/how-to-get-tabpage-on-which-a-user-control-data-type-resides)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This didn't work: passing a parameter through on the path to the ascx... e.g.

```xml
  <section ...> <tab ...> <control ...>  `landing.ascx?tab=importer`
```

But this will:

Create a page e.g. landing-importer.ascx and in that page include the landing.ascx control you want with the correct parameter.